# How to create history of data in workshop module?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop, foundry-object-views

I want to create a history of some metrics in workshop module on monthly basis and the user should be able to retrieve the data based on month selection.

I don't know how to create history for object sets, hence this question.

Comment: Are your objects having a timestamp ? So this is a question of "how do I bucket my objects in a specific month and then aggregate based on that" ? Or is that you are looking into the history of the values of the ontology (aka = I want to read the old value of my objects) ? 

If the former, Charts (bar chart) should be good enough, with the granularity on the time axis that you need.

Comment: I want to read the old value of my objects, for example I have some metrics that change monthly and I need to save metrics of previous month. The metrics are not directly dependent on timestamp property so cannot use it to plot graph to see history of values.

Comment: Are the objects modified by Actions or via the pipeline ?

Comment: objects are modified by actions

Comment: You can turn on Logs on the Action itself, so that you get a log/history of the edits performed by the users :)

Comment: Using action logs seems a great idea, but one question if we trigger some action through API will it log the values?

Comment: Yes ! As long as it goes through action it will log it. I'll write a proper answer on this SO thread.

Answer (score 1):

If your object is edited via Action, you can log the Edits performed by the user (who, what, etc.) by using [Action Logs](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/action-types/action-log/index.html). You can turn on Action Logging in the Ontology Manager Application (OMA) for this Action.

You can enable Logging on your Actions that edit the Object Type, and whenever the Action is triggered, it will create a "Log" (technically an instance of another Object Type "Log").

Logging will happen regardless of the place where the Action is triggered (in-platform, API, ...).
You can then use all the features and apps operating on Objects to analyze those Logs and create workflows on top.